# почему не показывается шаблон, а показывается какая-то хрень

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

вот базовый урл:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

вот урл приложения:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'index')
]
```

вот views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
        return render(request, 'polls/list.html'),
```

вот list.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}

{% block title %} 2 шаблон {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    БЛА-БЛА...

{% endblock %}
```

вот base.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>{% block title %} 1 шаблон {% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}



{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

структура такова:
Django = mysite = templates = polls(папка) и base.html = list.html
я написал весь этот код, но вместо норм шаблона мне показывает "AttributeError at /polls/", прямо на сайте

Comment: Шаблонизатор возвращает код ошибки и эта ошибка не всегда связанная с шаблоном.
1) Добавьте код ошибки в вопрос. 2) Сверьте свой код с туториалом, по которому вы работаете.

Comment: list.html такой путь? polls/templates/polls/list.html